# Explicitly using the namespace of the class attributes in methods to make code more readable?

Tags: c++

This question is about writing good code in terms of readability/best practices.

Especially when working with a larger class and methods, I would prefer to be verbose when using attributes of the class. A simple example would be changing the value of an attribute through a method. In python, this would be done like "self.some_attribute", where the "self." makes it verbose and readable imo.

In C++, there is different ways of doing it.

Without the namespace:

```
class Example{
    public:
        int size = 10;
        void setSize(int new_size){
            size = new_size;
        }
};
```

With the namespace:

```
class Example{
    public:
        int size = 10;
        void setSize(int new_size){
            Example::size = new_size;
        }
};
```

Is there a standard way to do it that's considered the better practice? I prefer the second, more verbose way but it can look ugly if the class name is big. Is there a different approach to go about this?

Another example for why I prefer the more verbose way is that if an input to the function has the same name as an atrribute, it won't throw an error but the attribute will not be modified:

```
class Example{
    public:
        int size = 10;
        void setSize(int size){
            size = size;
        }
};
```

Comment: The problem is that if you ask ten C++ developers "is <X> considered the better practice?" you will always get at least eleven different answers.

Comment: If you want something like pythons `self`, use `this`, as in `this->size = new_size;`

Comment: "_With the namespace_" ... `Example` is not a namespace.

Comment: `size = size;` in last example won't work, though. You'll need `this->size = size;` if you name both variables equally. This latter option would resemble most the pythonic way – even participated in a project where this was convention (not very well established, though). What you find pretty often is prefixing the member variables with a common pattern, e.g. `m_someMemberVariable`. I personally follow this pattern, too, since a while, but still no common sense among developers.

Comment: It appears you are looking for some [C++ Core Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik that's because there are that many ways to do it... With plenty of valid arguments for each. I don't like the stutter nor weird prefixes suffixes so I don't really understand the problems people have there, my IDE properly highlights member variables too and so I deal with these simply by writing `void set_size(int value) { size = value; }` here's yet another way.

Comment: Mostly useless as modern IDE will color member variable in a deifferent color than arguments. Adding `class_name::`, `this->` or `m_` give almost no benefit and make the code uglier. If a parameter has the same name, I would use `value` for a setter or `newSize` to make it obvious that the parameter is intended to be a new value.

Comment: Prefixing a variable with it class as in `class_name::variable_name` is **almost never done**. You might see a function prefixed with a base classe name to call base function. For variables, it is a bad practice to have same name as in a parent class. And finally, as one **should write short functions with not too much parameters**, it should not be necessary to make a distinction. And a good IDE also allows to hilight a variable anywhere in a function. Those alternatives would have make sense in 1990's but are irrelevant today.

Comment: @Beni, writing `set` (and `get`) methods for public member variables is not a good practice as you may always access and modify them explicitly once the class is initialized. On the other hand, suppose you want to write a `set` method for a private member variable, letting the variable have a `_` in its prefix or suffix - like `_size` or `size_` - is common and good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, `self.` is critical because Python is a dynamic language. Imagine that `self.` wouldn’t be required:

```py
class A:
  def f():
    x = 42 # whoops, is that a local or a member variable?
    del x # what is deleted here?
    return x # totally OK if there was another x in scope?
```

(the same problem effectively kills `with` in JS). But there is no such problem in C++! Each variable name is resolved at the time the method is compiled, and can’t change meaning afterwards.

So basically, while you definitely *can* access members via `this->`, there is little point in doing that.¹ All real IDEs are capable of highlighting members differently (some even distinguish own and inherited members). But from dark IDEless times, we still have common conventions of prefixing members with `m_` or suffixing them with `_` or likewise, as pointed out in the comments. That almost doesn’t hurt (esp. in comparison to `lpdwsmthHere`).

¹ Unless you’re writing a [curiously recurring template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) or likewise where you can’t refer to an inherited member by bare name, because before instantiation, it is unknown whether there *is* an inherited member with such name. Much like in Python, but still during compilation.